# Best way to encode information for input to neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, categorical-encoding, feature-engineering

If I have a 20x20 grid of cells, each cell can take on one of four values (Red, Green, Black, Blue)

What is the best way to encode this information?

My first guess would be that one hot encoding is a good idea in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no single "best" method, but probably the most straightforward would be to use one-hot encoding resulting with 20x20x4 tensor, where the encodings would be at the third dimension of it. Basically, this would be same as if you had images in four color scale but with the values rounded up to the extremes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by 'the encodings would be at the third dimension of it'?

Comment: Also would there be any advantage/disadvantage to scaling the max values from 255 to 1?

Comment: For the case of a neural net, scaling likely wont matter but, by convention, you should to between 0 and 1. Some models are sensitive to scaling.  As explained, an easy and good method would be to one hot encode the results.  The encoding being in the third dimension just means that your color encoding is after your x (1st) and y (2nd) dimension in your grid.

Comment: @KaneM your data is categorical (?), so there's no scaling. As about third dimension, I mean 20x20 $\to$ 20x20x4, with four layers per each one-hot code.